# Trouble added cell to UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Trying to add a cell to my ViewController, and I'm having trouble.  I'm wondering if I have all my delegates.  Currently, I can change the color of the collection view's background, but can't add any cells.

I'm using an array of text from my Listing() object to drive the collection view cells.  On viewDidLoad the length is 4.  I envisioned using this count for the numberofItemsInSection, however, if I put the print statement there it is never printed.  Which makes me think the wrong delegate is called and the method is never hit.  Correct?

```
import UIKit 

class ListingDetailViewController: UIViewController, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var listing = Listing()
    //    @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var post: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var amenitiesCollection: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationItem.title = listing.title
        self.amenitiesCollection!.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        print(listing.amenities.count)//printed 4

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        print(listing.amenities.count)
        return listing.amenities.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let identifier = "UICollectionViewCell"
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing `amenitiesCollection.reloadData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have linked the CollectionView delegate and datasource to your view controller.

In `viewDidLoad()` add:

```
    self.amenitiesCollection.delegate = self
    self.amenitiesCollection.dataSource = self
```

==================================

**EDIT:**

If you have already linked the delegate and dataSource, try reloading the collection view in `viewDidAppear(_:)`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.amenitiesCollection.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Did the trick.  I knew I left out datasource, I just didn't know how it fit in using an array. I'll up vote when the timer is done. Thanks

Comment: BTW, on a side note. If in declaration you are already mentioning the force unwrap like this, `var amenitiesCollection: UICollectionView!`. You don't need to force unwrap again when using it.